# Null incoming number in Marshmallow using PhoneStateListener

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm trying for call blocker and added below permission in manifest.

```
 <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

My code for receiver is:

```
public class PhoneCallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("CallBlockingPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean blockCalls=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("blockCall", false);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call block enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            PhoneCallStateListener customPhoneListener = new PhoneCallStateListener(context);
            telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
```

Code for comparing number:

```
  public PhoneCallStateListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setdefault.add("");
        editor = preferences.edit();
        switch (state) {

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                ArrayList<String> allBlockedNuber = new ArrayList<>();
                retrievePref = preferences.getStringSet("listOfBlockedNumbers", setdefault);
                allBlockedNuber.addAll(retrievePref);
                System.out.println(allBlockedNuber.size());
                System.out.println(incomingNumber);
      }
}
```

I'm getting null incoming number and error as:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10561 nor current process has android.permission.CALL_PHONE.

Mobile shows only one permission as Phone and that I have given manually. Then why error and not getting incoming number? Please guide.

Comment: take run time permission if you are targeting Android SDK >=23

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Request Permissions at Run Time

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html